# Given a list of numbers in which every number appear twice except one. Return that number

Tags: python, unique, xor, bitwise-xor

I was asked to find out the number from a list of numbers in Python that is present only once inside the list. As usual, I could easily solve it using the normal method that immediately comes out:

```
    class Solution(object):
        def singleNumber(self, nums):
            """
            :type nums: List[int]
            :rtype: int
            """
            for i in nums:
                if(nums.count(i) == 1):
                    return i
            return nums[0]
```

Trying to find out another better way, Internet suggested me to use Bitwise XOR operation and provided the following code which was way faster and more efficient. Below is the code:

```
    class Solution(object):
        def singleNumber(self, nums):
            """
            :type nums: List[int]
            :rtype: int
            """
            a = 0
            for i in nums:
                a^=i
                print(a)
            return a
```

The logic was if we do a XOR operation on 2 same bits(0,0 or 1,1) the answer will always be 0 and it will be 1 if the bits are different. Using this, it came out with such an approach.

My mind bogs down at trying to realize how is the normal concept of XOR operation coming to be useful here! I understand the logic they said about that same and different bits but by their code, every time I perform a XOR with the next bit a new number pops out so how can then we guarantee that only the number which occurs once will be evolved?

I feel clueless. It might not be a good approach to have posted a code snippet and then ask for an explanation but I feel the solution is extremely intriguing and am dying to learn how bitwise XOR helped out! Please help if anyone has an idea! Thanks in advance.

Note : In the list, all numbers occur twice except for one.

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](https://florian.github.io/xor-trick/) (specifically [this section](https://florian.github.io/xor-trick/#application-3-finding-the-duplicate-number)).

Comment: Does it help to know that this technique doesn't work for the list `[1,2,1,1]`?

Comment: Does it help to know that this technique still works for `[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3]`?

Comment: I think your question should be - **"Given a list of numbers in which every number occurs twice except for one. Return that number that occurs only once"**. This XOR method doesn't work if otherwise.

Comment: As per the other comments, this technique only works with a very specific kind of list of numbers.

Comment: @Ram its more like **"Given a list of numbers that all occur an equal amount of times and one number that occurs an odd number of times find the number that occurs odd times."**

Comment: Your XOR solution doesn't work if some numbers repeat odd number of times(3, 5, 7,...).

Comment: @PatrickArtner Is it **equal** or **even** number of times ?

Comment: @Ram thanks, should be **even** `[4, 3,3,3,3, 5,5,5,5,5,5,]` would be perfectly fine

Comment: @Ram I have updated my question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: @QUEEN Please go through my explanation in answers section.

Answer (score 1):

The general constraints for this XOR solution are a bit different:

**You have a list where exactly one number occurs an odd number of times and all other numbers occur an even number of times and need to find the *odd* one.**

XOR flips the bits if they are identical:

```
b1 XOR b1 > b0
b0 XOR b0 > b0
b1 XOR b0 > b1
b0 XOR b1 > b1
```

You have an arbitrary start value (the first number in your list), f.e.:

```
01010111011111101
```

If all other numbers occur an even number of times, you see each bit pattern at least twice.

The first time you have pairs of bits and

- flip every 0,1 bit to 1
- flip every 1,0 bit to 1
- flip every 1,1 bit to 0

then you encounter the same number again (because number even times in it):

- you have a 1 bit from last flipping and encounter a 1 bit again so you flip to 0
- you have a 1 bit from last flipping and encounter a 0 bit again so you stay at 1
- you have a 0 bit from last flipping and encounter a 1 bit again so you flip to 1

and you are now back at your original number because even times occuring numbers cancel out:

```
    101010010
xor 101010010
-------------
    000000000
```

and if you XOR any other number with 000000000 you get exactly that other number back.

Comment: Suppose I have the following list : [1,2,2,4,1]. After performing bitwise XOR operations, I get the following numbers 1,3,1,5,4. Every number becomes different but the answer says that for same numbers, XOR will return 0 else 1. How does it fit in here when we are getting different numbers at every step?

Comment: @Queen no. You do not apply it like that. You do: `q = [1,2,2,4,1]` - `a = q[0]` -  `for n in q[1:]: a = a^n` - afterwards `a` will be the one number that occures _odd_ times when all others occure _even_ times in your list. There is no need to store the intermediate numbers in a list as well.

Comment: Thank you and I understand  I need not store the intermediate numbers but I am wondering that the step ```a = a^n``` is yielding different numbers at every step so how come the consecutive XOR operations will produce the number asked for from the list?

Comment: I explained how - I can not understand it for you. Maybe the other answers are more clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think without knowing the properties of XOR operation, it is difficult to understand what that code does

This is the property of XOR operation

> **If the bits are the same, the result is 0. If the bits are different, the result is 1.**

Below table will give a clear idea of the above XOR property.

```
+---+---+---------+
| a | b | a XOR b |
+---+---+---------+
| 0 | 0 |    0    |
| 0 | 1 |    1    |
| 1 | 0 |    1    |
| 1 | 1 |    0    |
+---+---+---------+
```

#### The Solution to your question is based on this concept.

An interesting property of XOR is that

- **when you XOR the same number by itself even number of times you get a Zero**
- **when you XOR the same number by itself odd number of times you get the number itself**

Take for example - Number **2** (2 in binary is - 0010)

Let us

- Perform XOR of 2 *(even no. times)*

  ```
  0010
  0010
  ----
  0000   <- XOR (Value is 0)
  ```
- Perform XOR of 2 *(odd number of times)*

  ```
  0010
  0010
  0010
  ----
  0010   <- XOR (Value is 2)
  ```

*Whatever numbers are occuring for **even number of times** will eventually **result in a Zero** and **Zero XORed with the number occuring odd number of times will give you the same number** (that occurs odd number of times)*

And the reason why `a` is initialized to `0` is because - **`0` XOR `x` will give `x` itself**

Say x = 3

```
0 -> 0000
3 -> 0011
     ----
     0011  <- XOR (Value is 3)
```

##### Edit - Based on OP's doubt

For the input `arr = [1,2,2,4,1]` you are asking why you are getting arbitrary values - `1,3,1,5,4`

They are not arbitrary. They are the result of XOR operation between `a` and `i`.

Initial value of `a` = 0

- First Iteration: i = 1(0001); a = 0 (0000)

  ```
   i: 0000
   a: 0001
      ----
      0001   -> Decimal value is 1 stored in a
  ```
- Second Iteration: i = 2(0010); a = 1 (0001)

  ```
    i: 0010
    a: 0001
       ----
       0011   -> Decimal value is 3 stored in a
  ```
- Third Iteration: i = 2(0010); a = 3 (0011)

  ```
    i: 0010
    a: 0011
       ----
       0001   -> Decimal value is 1 stored in a
  ```
- Fourth Iteration: i = 4(0100); a = 1 (0001)

  ```
    i: 0100
    a: 0001
       ----
       0101   -> Decimal value is 5 stored in a
  ```
- Fifth Iteration: i = 1(0001); a = 5 (0101)

  ```
    i: 0001
    a: 0101
       ----
       0100   -> Decimal value is 4 stored in a
  ```

Comment: Suppose I have the following list : [1,2,2,4,1]. After performing bitwise XOR operations, I get the following numbers 1,3,1,5,4. Now at this point I would like to point out that the numbers coming out after XOR are arbitrary as in this example like 1,3,5 etc. Then how can this concept of bitwise XOR with same bits returns 0 or else 1 work here?

Comment: @QUEEN I have updated my answer based on your doubt. Please check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The relevant properties of the XOR operation are:

- It is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), so `(a ^ b) ^ c == a ^ (b ^ c)`
- It is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), so `a ^ b == b ^ a`
- It has `0` as an [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element), so `a ^ 0 == 0 ^ a == a`
- Every element is its own [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element), so `a ^ a == 0`

So consider what happens when your input list is like `[3, 4, 5, 4, 3]`. From the first two properties, we have that `(((3 ^ 4) ^ 5) ^ 4) ^ 3` is the same as `(3 ^ 3) ^ (4 ^ 4) ^ 5`, from the fourth property this is the same as `0 ^ 0 ^ 5`, and from the third property the result is `5`. Effectively, every element which appears an even number of times cancels out with itself, leaving just the element which occurs once (or an odd number of times).

Comment: One of the best solutions ever! Expalained with such transparency! Thank you so much!